# slick one-lineRs

Tags: r

What's your favorite one-liner in `R`?

Include a short companion example, and limit to one tip per post, please.
Note, `;` is cheating.

Example: calculate `x[i] / x[i-1]` for a vector `x`,

```
x <- 1:10
Reduce("/", as.data.frame(embed(x, 2)))
```

(collected from R-help, I forget who/when)

*Edit:* after some initial controversy, it looks like the question is now reopen for entries.

Comment: Too bad, I really would've like to see what else people come up with. Yours was really cool. Thanks!

Comment: Why is this subjective and argumentative?  Its either one line or it isn't and it does not seem argumentative to me either.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck: What's the question?  What's _your_ favorite one-liner in R?  It's a poll, it's not a question that could be objectively be answered.

Comment: Out of curiosity, had I phrased it "I'm looking for a concise piece of R code, limited to one line, yet providing a most elaborate example of R's functional programming paradigm in manipulating data."; would *that* have *fit in*?

Comment: The most upvoted question in the R label is "What statistics should a programmer (or computer scientist) know?" and the second most upvoted one is "What is the most useful R trick?".  If they are acceptable then I think this one should be too.

Comment: Now that this question is open again, it should be CW cause you won't get a single best anwser

Comment: Voted to close, not a real question. Please put this on your blog instead.

Comment: Am I the only one perplexed that regular R users don't seem to mind this unreasonable question?

Comment: @sixlettervariables, @BlueRaja, @KirkWoll, @dmckee, @Graviton [Very similar question in javascript tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472644/javascript-collection-of-one-line-useful-functions) and no closing votes. So why close this one? (more examples in [tips-and-tricks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tips-and-tricks) and [one-liner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/one-liner) tags).

Comment: @Marek: thank you for bringing those to my attention. However, some are old, thus "grandfathered". Others are on topic, others are not and I'll vote to close them.

Comment: Dear officious intermeddlers; I know you all are trying to do God's work by closing this question. However the [r] community on Stack Overflow likes this question quite a lot. Would you mind backing down from your religious zealotry on this one? Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to record the time that you created a file in its name (perhaps to make it unique, or prevent overwriting), then try this one-line function.

```
timestamp <- function(format = "%y%m%d%H%M%S")
{
  strftime(Sys.time(), format)
}
```

Usage is, e.g.,

```
write.csv(
   some_data_frame, 
   paste("some data ", timestamp(), ".csv", sep = "")
)
```

Answer (score 9):

Get odd or even indices.

```
odds <- function(x) seq_along(x) %% 2 > 0
evens <- function(x) seq_along(x) %% 2 == 0
```

Usage is, e.g.,

```
odds(1:5)
evens(1:5)
```

Comment: Or you could do the same without a one-liner with gtools pacakge by calling `odd()` and `even()` :)

Comment: Or using recycling `seq_len(5)[c(TRUE, FALSE)]`

Answer (score 6):

I often need fake data to illustrate, say, a regression problem. Instead of

```
X <- replicate(2, rnorm(100))
y <- X[,1] + X[,2] + rnorm(100)
df <- data.frame(y=y, X=X)
```

we can use

```
df <- transform(X <- as.data.frame(replicate(2, rnorm(100))), 
                y = V1+V2+rnorm(100))
```

to generate two uncorrelated predictors associated to the outcome `y`.

Comment: The one-liner is cute code, but I think the three line method is easier to understand.

Comment: @Richie Hey, but the OP ask for one-line :-)

Answer (score 6):

Removing NaNs - which are a nuisance every once in a while -  from a vector or dataframe (found somewhen on R-help)

```
is.na(x) <- is.na(x)
```

Example:

```
> x <- c(1, NaN, 2, NaN, 3, NA)
> is.na(x) <- is.na(x)
> x
[1]  1 NA  2 NA  3 NA
```

Answer (score 5):

Convert Excel dates to R dates.  Answer adapted from code by Paul Murrell.

```
excel_date_to_r_date <- function(excel_date, format)
{
  #excel_date is the number of days since the 0th January 1900.  See
  #http://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/ItDT/HTML/node67.html
  strftime(as.Date(as.numeric(excel_date) - 2, origin = "1900-01-01"), format)
}
```

Usage is, e.g.,

```
excel_date_to_r_date(40700, "%d-%m-%Y")
```

Comment: Did you check whether it works the same for Windows and Mac?

Comment: That minus 2 was killing me in some work I'm doing. So glad I stumbled on this.

Comment: @chl: Good point. I think, for a Mac, you can just change the `origin` value to `1904-01-01` and don't subtract the 2.  Volunteers with Macs appreciated to test this.

Answer (score 4):

Not quite what you are after, but fitting a multivariate linear regression model in one line is great:

```
lm(y ~ x1 + x2)
```

Answer (score 4):

`Reduce()` is a new kid on the block. The same can be done using `do.call()`, and is a little bit quicker (on my system at least):

```
do.call("/", as.data.frame(embed(1:10, 2)))

R> do.call("/", as.data.frame(embed(1:10, 2)))
[1] 2.000000 1.500000 1.333333 1.250000 1.200000 1.166667 1.142857 1.125000
[9] 1.111111
R> Reduce("/", as.data.frame(embed(1:10, 2)))
[1] 2.000000 1.500000 1.333333 1.250000 1.200000 1.166667 1.142857 1.125000
[9] 1.111111
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes good sense, more than `Reduce` in fact.

Comment: exp(diff(log(x)))) is even little bit quicker

Comment: @Wojciech Sobala Neat, though you might run into problems with negative values, I'd imagine.

Comment: @baptiste if you don't exclude negative values in x you can't exclude 0, so you have problem anyway.

Comment: @baptiste: "imagine" -- _get it_?

Comment: @sehe clearly, that should read "i'd"

Answer (score 3):

Function summarize the amount of missing data for each variable in a data frame. Returns a list.

```
propmiss <- function(dataframe) lapply(dataframe,function(x) data.frame(nmiss=sum(is.na(x)), n=length(x), propmiss=sum(is.na(x))/length(x)))
```

Not a one-liner, but returning this info as a data frame is more useful.

```
propmiss <- function(dataframe) {
    m <- sapply(dataframe, function(x) {
        data.frame(
            nmiss=sum(is.na(x)), 
            n=length(x), 
            propmiss=sum(is.na(x))/length(x)
        )
    })
    d <- data.frame(t(m))
    d <- sapply(d, unlist)
    d <- as.data.frame(d)
    d$variable <- row.names(d)
    row.names(d) <- NULL
    d <- cbind(d[ncol(d)],d[-ncol(d)])
    return(d[order(d$propmiss), ])
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Wipes the slate clean removes all objects from the memory.

`rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))`

Answer (score 2):

Multiple columns edit is one of my favourite.

E.g. to change all numeric columns to characters:

```
X <- iris
X[id] <- lapply(X[id <- sapply(X, is.numeric)], as.character)
```

or standardize them

```
X[id] <- lapply(X[id <- sapply(X, is.numeric)], scales)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd say look at `plyr` for a package full of slick oneliners!

Comment: an example in particular? (I know I have mine)

Answer (score 1):

Well, not really a oneliner but textConnection is great!

```
x <- "1,3
1,a
1,g,4
3,d,6
2,X,1,3
2,K"
read.table(textConnection(x), sep=",", header=FALSE, na.strings="", fill=TRUE)
```

result

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  1  3 NA NA
2  1  a NA NA
3  1  g  4 NA
4  3  d  6 NA
5  2  X  1  3
6  2  K NA NA
>
```

Comment: one annoying side-effect of using `textConnection` in such a one-liner is that you get warnings when the connection closes later on. I usually have three lines; one to open, one to read, one to close the connection.

Comment: @baptiste you can make it a one line by assigning *inline* `read.table(con <- textConnection(x), sep=",",....` and then tag `; close(con)` on the end of the one-liner to close the connection. Ugly as but...

Comment: @Gavin Simpson yeah, I suppose, though I wouldn't do that. Also, "real" one-liners should not use `;` i reckon.

Comment: See `text_to_table` for a convenience wrapper to `textConnection`.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936285/is-there-a-way-to-use-read-csv-to-read-from-a-string-value-rather-than-a-file-in/3941145#3941145

Answer (score 1):

Here's another tip collected from R-help (if memory serves, by Romain François).

Remove existing variables from the workspace:

```
rm( list = Filter( exists, c("a", "b") ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

My favorite one-liner can be found in the help pages of the `%in%` function and is basically its opposite.

```
f.wo <- function(x, y) x[!x %in% y]
```

Wrapped up into a nice, small function it comes really handy. E.g.

```
R> f.wo(c("a", "b", "c"), "b")
[1] "a" "c"
R> f.wo(1:8, c(2,7))
[1] 1 3 4 5 6 8
```

Comment: Can be made to look more like %nin% by putting this in your profile: 

"%nin%" <- function(x, y) !(x %in% y)

Comment: @StephenTurner There was question about it: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5831794/168747. I prefer direct definition of `%nin%`

Answer (score 1):

Function to read space delimited data from the clipboard

```
read.cb <- function(...) read.table(file="clipboard", ...)
```

e.g.

```
# read data from the clipboard with a header
d<-read.cb(T) 

#read data from clipboard without header
d<-read.cb()
```

Answer (score 1):

Function to convert columns of data in a data frame to factor variables

```
factorcols <- function(d, ...) lapply(d, function(x) factor(x, ...))
```

E.g. convert columns 1-4 in data frame d to factor variables

```
d[1:4] <- factorcols(d[1:4])
```

Answer (score 1):

Return a new matrix, where the rows of the original matrix are sorted by columns:

```
newmat <- t(apply(orimat, 1, sort))
```